# Why generic constraint T extends Comparable<T> is not sufficient to avoid a cast?

Tags: java

I have a class like this:

```
public class AbstractParameter<T extends Comparable> {
  ....
    public void validate(T tempVal, StringBuilder msg) {
        if(tempVal.compareTo(new Integer(0)) != 0 ) {
            //do something
        }
    }
  ....
}
```

The tempVal will be an Integer. It compiles and runs fine. But if I change the **T extends Comparable** to **`T extends Comparable<T>`** Above if statement generated the following compile error:

```
required: T#1
found: Integer
reason: actual argument Integer cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
  T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class AbstractParameter
  T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable
```

I can cast the **new Integer(0)** to **T** to remove the compile error. My question is should I use `public class AbstractParameter<T extends Comparable>` or `public class AbstractParameter<T extends Comparable<T>>`?

I guess the `public class AbstractParameter<T extends Comparable<T>>` should be the way to go but that `(T)new Integer(0)` cast seems annoyance. Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: How do you know (or can enforce) that `tempVal` will be an `Integer` or can be compared to an `Integer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the type of the parameter to `Comparable<T>.compareTo()` is T, and you are sending an integer, which is not compatible. Ask yourself this: if you know that `tempVal` is an `Integer`, why do you declare it as T?

Answer (score 0):

**public abstract class AbstractParameter implements Comparable** will produce compilation error because inside `validate` you are invoking `compareTo` on `tempVal` and Since there is no Upperbound on T(T can be anything) the compiler can't resolve method `tempVal.compareTo(...)`

You mentioned that "The tempVal will be an Integer" in your post. So change the class definition to include this info in order to avoid unchecked warning

```
public abstract class AbstractParameter<T extends Comparable<Integer>>
```